# Putting js at the end of the page

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
    <div class="actions">
        <h3>Actions</h3>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="/configurations">Configurations</a></li>
        </ul>               
    </div>


<script type="text/javascript" src="/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        $('ul a').click(function(){
                   alert("");
            });
</script>
```

In the above code is document.ready necessary. What i mean is, is there any case when js will be executed before html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.ready` is a shortcut to `DOMContentLoaded` (or `onreadystatechange` or an assortment of workarounds for other browsers). That event fires when the DOM has been built - in other words, when the whole HTML has been downloaded.

So, as long as your script tags are the last thing before `</body>` (they are not inside any `div`s or other elements) the end result is the same, you don't need `$(document).ready`. That is even recommended, since putting your scripts in the `<head>` will slow down the loading of content.

Though I'd recommend you to adopt this pattern, to avoid problems with the `$` global:

```
<script>
(function($){
    $('ul a').click(function(){
        alert("")
    })
})(jQuery)
</script>
```

These other questions are interesting reads:

- [How does jQuery's "document ready" function work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5959194/how-does-jquerys-document-ready-function-work)
- [Does putting scripts on the bottom of a web page speed up page load?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/855077/does-putting-scripts-on-the-bottom-of-a-web-page-speed-up-page-load)
- [When do you choose to load your javascript at the bottom of the page instead of the top?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1860482/when-do-you-choose-to-load-your-javascript-at-the-bottom-of-the-page-instead-of)
- [Benefits of loading JS at the bottom as opposed to the top of the document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5329807/benefits-of-loading-js-at-the-bottom-as-opposed-to-the-top-of-the-document)

Comment: `jQuery(function($) { })` is a better way of doing it. It doesn't really cost anything to use document ready here, and it'd cause confusion if you moved the code at a later date.

Comment: "better" here is subjective - the check for .ready is unnecessary. Using closures like this should be well understood by most.

Answer (score -1):

In your case, it seems there is no problem.
But, when you use pictures (`<img />`), there is a possibility for the document to execute your function (it fires "ready" event) even if the pictures aren't displayed yet.

Comment: document.ready fires when DOM is loaded, it doesn't wait for the images to load.

Comment: You're thinking of the `load` event. `DOMReady` fires before images are loaded.