# js file loaded by pjax can't use jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, pjax

I just build a site use PJAX, I have include the `jquery.min.js` at the end of template html file. But when I load one page with js file link in it. The file just get an error:

```
$ is not defined
```

I can't figure it out.
Thank you all for your help!

Comment: It may be that your jquery reference is not above all your other scripts.  Try putting it all the way at the top in the `<head>` tag, just for testing purposes.

Comment: yeah! test pass. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14352632/jquery-sources-position-in-html-file-is-important-or-not?lq=1) explains the position of jQuery script.

You can see from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/855108/2002412) that people recommend putting the script at the bottom of the page, because it allows rendering of the page sooner.  However, you can't reference the script if it hasn't been loaded yet.

If you don't fully understand how it works, no offense but I think it will be fine to load the script in the `<head>` as recommended above, you probably won't see too much rendering difference as a beginner.