# jquery library place it on body?

Tags: jquery

My question is simple, but I have not found any answer for this.

**1**. Where should I place the **jquery library**? in the body or head?
I'm asking about the jquery library, not about my jquery's.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**2**. Is there any problem if I put **MY** jquery's in the end of body with:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
```

? I know I need this in the head, not in the body, what I want to know is if it can slow my page or something like this, because I want to leave this tag if in the future I decided to place it in head again.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where is the best place to put <script> tags in HTML markup?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/436411/where-is-the-best-place-to-put-script-tags-in-html-markup)

Comment: @AshrafPurno no, my question is not about <script>, my question is about the jquery library.

Comment: `jquery library` is nothing special. It's just a bunch of `javascript`. So it is same as any other `<script>` tag.

Comment: what you mean by " jquery library"?

Comment: So I can place it where I want?

Comment: the jquery, from jquery.com @vijayP

Comment: Yes. just make sure to include it before your scripts where you use `jQuery` provided bits.

Comment: if the jquery is from jquery.com then it should be in `<head>` tag ideally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best practices recomends:

- Libraries goes to `head` section.
- Your jquery code should go to `head` section inside `<script>` tag or external `js`file.

**You have to place your jQuery code after the jQuery library**

you can place your `<script>` tags at the top or bottom of the page. Some users used to place the tag at the bottom to ensure the page is rendered when control reach the script code, but for that it's recommended you use the `ready` jQuery event placed at page top.

Comment: thank you friend! so I will put the jquery library in the head and my jquery's in the bottom!

Comment: It's not necesary to put your code at the bottom. Put it at head using correctly the `ready` event.

Comment: isn't it faster if I put it at the bottom?

Comment: If you are putting scrips on the head of your site, don't forget to use async or defer, otherwise this aproach is worse than putting at the bottom.

Comment: Check this, it explains: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/855077/does-putting-scripts-on-the-bottom-of-a-web-page-speed-up-page-load

Comment: @madagalbiati thank you! I will place  async in my head scripts!